# UK standard visitor visa employment letter

Tags: standard-visitor-visas, chinese-citizens, conferences

I am a Chinese citizen who plans to apply for a UK standard visitor visa in China to attend a conference in the UK in July 2019. I just finished my first job contract, which is at a U.S. university, and I will be employed as an instructor at another U.S. university in August 2019.

The time when I apply for UK visa and attend the conference is in the gap between the time I finish my first employment but have not yet begun my second employment. Is it okay that I provide the employment letter from my future employer?

Since I apply for the visa in China, must the employment letter be from a Chinese employer, even through I am a Chinese citizen and have savings of my own and have a permanent house with my parents?

Answer (score 1):

The UK does not care what country you work in when applying for a visitor visa (except that it cannot be the UK, of course).

The fact that you are starting new employment after your trip to the UK actually works in your favor. It demonstrates that you have a good reason to depart the UK, and thus makes it more likely that you will be approved for the visa.